# if else endif oneliner in VIM

Tags: vimscript

I have this oneliner in my `vimrc` but it does not work :

```
if has("patch-7.4.710") | set listchars+=space:· else | set listchars+=trail:· | endif
```

VIM says :

```
E518: Unknown option: else
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to put another `|` before `else` otherwise vim will think your command is `set listchars+=space:· else` instead of two separate commands. That's why you got the error message: `else` is an unknown option for the command `set`.

The correct syntax is the following:

```
if has("patch-7.4.710") | set listchars+=space:· | else | set listchars+=trail:· | endif
```

Comment: I was struggling to where would I place the `|`, before or after the `else` ? Now, I now it's both :-D. Thanks a lot :) !

Comment: @SebMa: Think of how vim would parse your code if it was written on several lines: instruction 1 `if has("patch-7.4.710")`, instruction 2 `set listchars+=space:·`, instruction 3 `else`, instruction 4 `set listchars+=trail:·` and last instruction `endif`. As the `|` are used to separate instructions it is only logical to put one before `else` and one after :)

Comment: It's logical as long as one knows the language. In C, we use `;` to separate instructions . In C `else` is not an instruction, otherwise there would be a `;` after it :)

Comment: Yup that's a good point. VimL can be tricky sometimes.

Comment: The semantics of VimScript are a lot closer to shell scripting than C @SebMa.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker In shell, here is the syntax of a oneliner `if else fi` statement :
`if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi`
As you can see, there is no instruction separator right after the `else` statement like in VimL

Comment: @SebMa No, but the semantics of "(almost) everything including control structures are a command" is similar to VimScript (and different from C).