# if endif oneliner failure in VIM

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, syntax-highlighting

I followed [QA_1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13536/47349).

I use `vim 9.1.0` instead of `nvim` which seems to [also have the following bug](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8796#issuecomment-733064593) and I have the following in `foo.vim` at line 67:

```
if g:LOG_MSG==v:true | echow "g:mode_class " | else | echo "" | endif
```

Here when `g:LOG_MSG=v:true` it will `echow "g:mode_class "` and all is fine. But when `g:LOG_MSG=v:false`, it will throw `line   92: E171: Missing :endif` (Notice it is at line 92 instead of 67). And when I do `:if g:LOG_MSG==v:true | echow "g:mode_class " | else | echo "" | endif` in the command mode it works all well.

---

By [QA_2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30405896/21294350), here `echow` may be probably not the source of this problem.

IMHO, it is probably due to `if v:false` will skip all the following in that line. And multi-line `if else endif` block works.

---

The minimal reproduction:

```bash
$ cat ~/.vim/tmp/if_endif.vim
if v:false | echow "g:mode_class " | else | echo "" | endif
$ echo "" > ~/.tmp.vimrc;vim --noplugin -u ~/.tmp.vimrc -c ":source ~/.vim/tmp/if_endif.vim"
Error detected while processing command line..script /c/Users/czg/.vim/tmp/if_endif.vim:
line    2:
E171: Missing :endif
```

Q:

How to make `if else endif` oneliner work in VIM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is within `echo(w)` as it can't figure out where is the end of the command.

A workaround is to wrap it with `execute`:

```
if v:false | exe 'echow "g:mode_class "' | else | exe 'echo ""' | endif
```